# page area not refreshing using jquery and setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

i am trying to refresh a particular area of my php page, which will load the updated information from database. My code are working on localhost. But, when the same code i'm trying to execute on my domain. Then, it is not refreshing and not showing updated information, and i don't why... Anybody have any idea..

```
setInterval(updateShouts, 10000 );
function updateShouts(){    
$('#refresh').load('ajax/check.php');
};
```

this is the code, which i'm using for refreshing the
    .

Comment: can you paste the live link ?

Comment: Is the setInterval actually going off? Try adding a console.log to the  function.

Is the URL correct? Watch the network connection on firebug/chrome dev tools.

Is the selector right? Well... is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check that the URL is correct:

You can use Firebug (or another Javascript debugger) to watch the request going out, and you can see if it was a 404 error or if it worked.

Also, in the Console, just type in $('#refresh') and make sure it returns an actual object.
if it just displays [] or undefined, then the selector is wrong.

Comment: To be clear, I mean checking Firebug when its on your domain, so you can see any error messages...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function updateShouts()
{    
   $('#refresh').load('ajax/check.php');
};

setInterval(function(){updateShouts();}, 10000 );
```

Problem is with most localhost dev servers the configuration, security, etc.. is usually at the load end of the scale vs a host else where. So that may or may not be part of the issue, I couldn't say for sure though

**Edit** I agree with the notion of checking to make sure the path ajax/check.php is valid also. And that Firebug is a very handy tool to have when developing with jquery (or javascript stand alone)

Comment: But.. my question is.. why it is working fine on localhost, why not online... how can i check whether it is retrieving the page information...any idea..

Comment: All understand your question :) and they are answering right asking to check the path, path can be different than your local server or paste the live link here...

Comment: FireBug is step one if you don't already have it. Why. Because if your script is errored anywhere it will tell you that. If there is an error with the script the script might be halting. Also with firebug if the .load() event isnt working properly it will tell you that as well. There are one to many reasons why your script could be failing. To list them out fully.. Could be your PHP could be your script, could be a mix of the 2, could be your own human error. Could be that your local environment is not as tight as your paid environment.. could be something entirely different.